# Changing DroidParts ClearableEditText icon

Tags: android, droidparts

Could you give a tip, how to change clear icon to icon from Holo theme? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](http://droidparts.org/widgets.html). To use the native Holo icon:

```
<org.droidparts.widget.ClearableEditText
    // ...
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear" />
```